# Adding files and text in C++ Cpp?

Tags: c++, file, error-handling, compiler-errors

Sorry if my English is not great I speak Serbian but I will try.

I am trying to make it so the user can input text and name the file by using the code I put behind this but it will ask me what I want to put in the text like I am supposed to but then it asks for the file name and then it gives me the error message right after. What is going wrong? I can make my speaking clearer about something if you ask.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int userTextInput, userFileName;

        cout << "What would you like to add to your new file? " << endl;

        cin >> userTextInput;

        cout << "What would you like the file to be named? (please include the extension)" << endl;

        cin >> userFileName;

        fstream myFileHandler;

        myFileHandler.open("userFileName");

        myFileHandler << userTextInput << endl;

        if (myFileHandler.is_open()) {
                cout <<  "Your text has been added :)" << endl;
        } else {
                cout <<  "There has been an error" << endl;
        }

        myFileHandler.close();
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: The file with the name "userFileName" does not exist. Maybe you wanted `myFileHandler.open(userFileName);` if you have a modern compiler that supports the 2011 standard or `myFileHandler.open(userFileName.c_str());` if you have a 10 year old compiler or stuck with the 2003 or older standard.

Comment: `int userTextInput, userFileName;` should a filename really be an integer? No, both of these should be `std::string` so in addition to my first comment change `int userTextInput, userFileName;` to `std::string userTextInput, userFileName;`

Comment: Unrelated: Don't tag it with the `C` language tag - this is not `C`.

Comment: @displayName456 CPP Reference is a good starting point, including some nice examples: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/

Comment: @rturrado You mentioned the better of the two sites but linked to the other :-) Here's a link to cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks!